# Are conservation of mass and conservation of energy *independent* constraints for physical systems?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, mass, conservation-laws, models

I'm modeling fluid systems and want to use conservation of mass (aka 'continuity') and conservation of energy as constraints to help solve for certain system parameters. But it occurred to me that the two constraints may not be independent and may make parameter identification difficult.

Are the two constraints always independent? If not does independence depend on the structure of the system?

My thoughts, fluid systems are almost always nonlinear. And if I'm not mistaken nonlinearity often invokes dependence.

Comment: For some systems they are superfluous. For example, in library elasticity you don't need to use conservation of energy or mass.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to solve exactly -- under some constraints, fluid systems will decouple the energy equation from the rest of the system (low Mach numbers for example). In others, they are tightly coupled because large internal energy changes can lead to large density changes and vice-versa. What kinds of systems are you interested in?

Comment: Another important point when it comes to actually writing code to solve a model -- generality in equations can greatly reduce accuracy under limiting conditions. I'm happy to help point you in the right direction if you can give some more info on what kinds of systems you are looking at.

Comment: Docscience, the two constraints you mentioned should be independent of each other.  If you could give more details, it would be easier to be certain of this.

Comment: If we use the equation of state in the form $p=p(\rho)$ then the energy equation can be integrated independently.

Comment: @tpg2114 I was interested in more of a general sense, but my specific problem, subsonic gas flow in conduits.

Comment: @tpg2114 ... but where both density changes and viscosity have an influence.

Comment: @docscience Are the density and viscosity changes due to temperature variation alone, or are they due to pressure changes also? In other words, is it low speed subsonic, like Mach under 0.3, or is it subsonic-yet-compressible? And is it single-component gases, or are the multiple species gases?

Comment: @tpg2114 both temperature and pressure can affect change in these properties. 'subsonic-yet-compressible' and mixed gases. The specific element, structure I'm focused on creates a quadratic relation between pressure drop and volumetric flow. So two parameters to model. One parameter mostly influenced by density change, the other by viscosity. A mix of Bernoulli and Pouiselle.